# Need to use captcha validation for mobile app forms?

Tags: mobile, captcha, spam, intel-xdk

I am making a HTML5 mobile app via XDK. I have some forms which I use Captcha validation in the website. In my prospective, comment spam for a mobile app doesn't make any scenes. Does anyone see any comment spam for mobile apps? Do you think I need to use Captcha validation in a mobile app form or leave it to not to bother the users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to prevent comment spam and spam bots in both websites and hybrid apps is to create the form dynamically by JS or jQuery instead of putting the form in the view (HTML codes) directly. In this way you don't need to put Captcha to protect it from bots. Here is a sample code for creating a form with jQuery:

```
// Make THE FORM tag
var $form = $("<form/>", {
  appendTo : $("#contactFormSection"),
  class    : "col-xs-12 col-sm-11",
  id       : "contactForm",
  submit   : AJAXSubmitForm
});

//MAKE A HIDDEN INPUT
$("<input/>",{
  type        : "hidden",
  name        : "flag", // Needed for serialization
  value       : "5",
  appendTo    : $("#nameSection"),
  on          : {        // Yes, the jQuery's on() Method 
    /*
    input : function() {
      console.log( this.value );
    }
    */
  }
});

//Make Name INPUT
$("<input/>",{
  type        : "text",
  class       : "formContact", 
  id          : "exampleInputName2",
  name        : "name", // Needed for serialization
  placeholder : "Your Name",
  appendTo    : $("#nameSection"),
  on          : {        // Yes, the jQuery's on() Method 

  }
});

//MAKE EMAIL INPUT
$("<input/>",{
  type        : "email",
  class       : "formContact", 
  id          : "exampleInputEmail1",
  name        : "email", // Needed for serialization
  placeholder : "Your Email",
  appendTo    : $("#emailSection"),
  on          : {        // Yes, the jQuery's on() Method 

  }
});

//MAKE TEXTAREA 
$("<textarea/>",{
  class       : "formContact-text", 
  rows        : "3",
  name        : "msg", // Needed for serialization
  placeholder : "Your message",
  appendTo    : $("#msgSection"),
});

//submit the form
function AJAXSubmitForm(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default Form Submission
  // do AJAX instead:
  var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    url: "Your server API URL",
    type: "POST",
    data: serializedData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      // log the data sent back from PHP
      if(data.status){
        $('#confirmation').modal('show');
      } else{
        $('#errorMsg').modal('show');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment spam happens on both mobile and desktop websites or applications. The commonly used **text** Captcha validation helps to remedy this problem.

When it comes to mobile apps, it is harder to automate data submission within native apps. The reason is due in part to the inability to write malicious foreign scripts to discover elements within the source code and invoke form submissions. Plus, mobile applications must be purchased (free or paid) and installed on a physical device or in a simulator.

CAPTCHAs that are more ideal for mobile apps: [sliderCAPTCHA](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1138), [imageCAPTCHA](http://confidenttechnologies.com/products/confident-captcha-mobile), [motionCAPTCHA](http://www.josscrowcroft.com/projects/motioncaptcha-jquery-plugin/), [RingCAPTCHA](http://ringcaptcha.com/en/), and [NuCAPTCHA](http://techcrunch.com/2011/10/05/nucaptcha-brings-user-friendly-captchas-to-mobile-phones-and-tablets/).